# How to call plugin controller from url in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an admin Panel plugin named as PanelAdmin. 
This is CategoriesController.php

```
<?php

namespace PanelAdmin\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class CategoriesController extends AppController
{
public function initialize()

    {

        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent

    }

public function index()

    {

        $this->set('topics', $this->categories->find('all'));

    }

    }

?>
```

This is Topics View inside Template/Topics/index.ctp

```
<h1>Blog topics</h1>

<p><?= $this->Html->link('Add Topic', ['action' => 'add']) ?></p>

<table>

    <tr>

        <th>Id</th>

        <th>Title</th>

        <th>Created</th>

        <th>Actions</th>

    </tr>
```

I want to call the PanelAdmin directly and it should show the above view but right now i got following error :

```
Error: CategoriesController could not be found.
```

It it searching in the main src folder i want it to search into plugin folder when i hit http://localhost/multi_shopping/PanelAdmin this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add routes connecting to /PanelAdmin

```
$routes->connect('/PanelAdmin', [
    'plugin' => 'PanelAdmin', 
    'controller' => 'Categories', 
    'action' => 'index'
]);
```

Comment: This to be added in the routes.php file of plugin PanelAdmin or in main routes.php file

Answer (score 0):

First  make  sure your plugin is loaded https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-configuration.

You  don't need to define routes in your plugin to access your plugin controllers in the url,  cakephp  default routes  Will automatically make  your controllers accessible as **/panel-admin/categories**